# Fetch dropped packet count of an interface with netlink sockets

Tags: c, linux-kernel, netlink

I am familiar with different tools (like netstat, tcpdump, etc.) and files (like `/sys/class/net/<dev>/statistics`) with which we can get the count.

But can anyone tell me if there is a way of getting that information directly from the kernel, using netlink sockets?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, take a look at `IFLA_STATS`. You may want to check the `ifstat.c` file of the `iproute2` package, which is pretty much the standard tool to interact with netlink.